# IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2 in Sklearn LabelEncoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I've been trying to create a DL model for a practice purpose using ANN. I've a fake bank's customer data in which there are two categorical variable i.e gender and country.

I tried to encode country variable but got below error which I don't have with the gender variable.

Error:

> X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
>   IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

My Code:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('.\Artificial_Neural_Networks\Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataframe.iloc[:, [3, 13]].values
Y = dataframe.iloc[:, -1].values

# Encodeing categorical data
# for country column
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
# print(X)

# for gender column
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
print(X)
```

P.S: I use Pycharm and novice in Deep Learning.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your X dataset doesn`t have enough columns.

In this line you select only two columns from data frame.so it has indexes of 0 and 1.

```
X = dataframe.iloc[:, [3, 13]].values
```

And in this line you trying to get index of 2,Thats why you get the **index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2** error.

```
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I've to see indexes documentation again!